# Detecting leaks in Cocoa thread?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsthread

I have been working on an application in Xcode for a while now and had previously detected a lot of memory leaks using Instruments. Fast forward a few months and I have added threading to my application and Instruments will not show any memory leaks even though it has a growing memory footprint.

Does Instruments not detect memory leaks in threads I create? What could be the reason for these leaks flying under the radar?

Comment: With what are you creating your threads?(pthreads, NSThread, NSRunloop,etc), Also do you have NSZombiesEnabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaks just means objects for which there is no references to said objects.   If your app is allocating memory and filling, say, a cache or some global dictionary or whatever, it'll grow unbounded and show nary a leak.

You'll probably want to use [Heapshot based analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) to track it down.